# ASP.Net MVC3 - 403 Forbidden Access Denied

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been through all of the related issues on this one but cannot find a solution or a question that matches the issue I have.  All the related questions related to a site not working at all.  Mine is working occasionally.

I have a site that has been created using MVC 3.  I've deployed it to a shared hosting provider (Web Fusion in the UK) and have bin deployed all of the relevant DLL's.

The problem I am getting is that the site is randomly displaying a 403.  It works from some devices (iPad, iPhone, Win7 Phone) and sometimes from my PC in Firefox, Safari and IE9.

However, it is also then stopping working and going back to displaying forbidden.

I'm stumped, the hosting company are looking at it and I don't think it is me but has anyone ever seen this?  I would expect the site to either work or not work, not work occasionally!

I'm wondering if it is caching, I've cleared the history to no avail.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? As I don't have that much hair left to pull out.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem on the server.  Are you using directories to store/read data like an `App_Data` directory?

Comment: No, everything comes from a SQL DB.  The odd thing is that it works from some machines/devices but not others.  It almost seems like a DNS issue but obviously it is getting to the site, so it isn't that... Thanks.

Comment: And now it is all working again!  If I get a reply from the hosting company I will post it here in case anyone else hits it.

Comment: Well, shortly after it started working it stopped again.  The it started then it stopped etc.  I have had no response from the hosting company (web fusion in the UK).  It looks almost like the site is load balanced and not all of the files have been migrated but I have had no confirmation.

Comment: I've moved the site completely to discount asp .net and it worked immediately and I have no problems any more.  I am still awaiting some feedback from the original hosts but I am not hopeful from their lack of replies so far...

Comment: Sounds like your previous hosting provider knows nothing about Permissions.